# Understanding MySQL explain, `rows`-wise

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I'm trying to figure out how should I take into account the `rows` column of MySQL `explain`'s output. Here's what [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain_rows) says about it:

> The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must
>   examine to execute the query.

So here are my questions:

1. Regardless of its exactness, is this the number of records that are going to be examined after the indices are used or before?
2. Is it correct that I need to value the optimization of tables with high `rows`?
3. Is it true that the total number of records MySQL will examine is the product of `rows` column?
4. What are the strategies to reduce the `rows`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The meaning of indexes is - that DBMS will look there *first*, and then use gathered information to look up matched rows. So - yes, `rows` will indicate how many rows will be examined *after* indexes were used (if they are present & applicable, of course). This question means that you are confused of what indexes are. They're not some magic, they are just real data structure. They entire sense is to reduce count of data rows used to perform query.
2. Arguable. This question can't be answered "yes" or "no". Because different tables may have different row definition - and the applied operation would be also different. Imagine that you have `100.000` rows from first table and `10.000` rows from second. But for first table you're selecting just plain value while for second table - something like standard deviation. That is: not only count of rows matters, but also what are you doing with them.
3. You may think of it as about multiplication, yes. But the thing is - it's not *exact* what will happen. And not exact count, of course. There is also `filtered` field that indicates for many rows were affected by applied conditions (like in `WHERE` clause). But - in general, you may estimate end result as power of `10`, i.e. if you have `123.456.789` rows in first line and `111.222` in second, you may treat is as "selection of around 1E8 x 1E5" rows.
4. The techniques are quite standard and they all are about optimization of your query. First step is to take a look about [how MySQL optimizes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html) certain parts of query. Not all queries can be optimized - and in general it is too broad question, because some solutions may touch entire database and/or application structure. But understanding how to use indexes properly, what can be (and what can not be) indexed, how to create effective index - will be enough.

Comment: About the 4th question: A list of strategies would be fine. e.g. tuning indices, partitions (perhaps!). I'm not looking for complete solutions, just pointers what can affect the `rows`.

Comment: There's no any _strategy_. As follows, from answer to point 1, proper indexes will reduce count of rows. But what if you have `SELECT * FROM t`? That's why in common case we can not say anything about reducing count of rows. What else it could be? Use partitioning. Or adjust database structure so it will fit your application requests better. That's it. No magic, only hard work.

Comment: If only an index is used to look up matched rows, should `rows` be 0?